# Как получить в одном запросе прямую и обратную последовательность в двух разных столбцах?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть запрос :

```
SELECT 
    addressCode
FROM action
```

Выведет точки маршрута например :
1
2
3

Мне нужно еще один столбец что бы результат был такой :
1|3
2|2
3|1

Как это сделать? inner join это же поле? Я уже думал сделать временную таблицу и во временной таблице апдейтить последний столбец перевернутым результатом. посоветуйте как правильно сделать?

Comment: Можна, если пронумеровать строки, и присоиденить "согласно нумерации", но... это будет упорядочено, а если не упорядочено то запрос будет ещё сложнее.

Comment: @nick_n_a, если пронумеровать и присоединить согласно нумерации, что Вы имеете ввиду row_number и временную таблицу? Все равно не понимаю каким ключом соединять. В идеале это  SELECT addressCode, addressCode1 FROM action тут join order by addressCode asc, addressCode1 desc, если бы оно перевернуло столбцы не зависимо друг от друга

Comment: Поменять крыс местами нельзя. Один курсор возвращает однозначно **одну** строку.  Можно через временную. Мне кажется лучше то что вы делаете реализовать на языке высокого уровня:)

Comment: @nick_n_a это для rdl отчета

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно, пример с вложеными запросами, думаю лучше переписать на временную таблицу, но так тоже можно.

```
select *  from (
select   row_number() over (order by (select null)) rn  ,addressCode from action   -- этот кусок можно вынести в временную таблицу
) t1 
left join 
(
  select   row_number() over (order by (select null)) rn  ,addressCode from action   -- этот кусок можно вынести в временную таблицу
) t2 on t1.rn =  (select count(*) from action) -  t2.rn + 1 -- и сюда в к-во тоже подставить временную
```

Если вам подойдёт упорядоченый список то лучше так, но тогда без временной таблицы:

```
select *  from (
select   row_number() over (order by addressCode asc) rn  ,addressCode from action  
) t1 
left join 
(
  select   row_number() over (order by addressCode desc) rn  ,addressCode from action  
) t2 on t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Comment: почему **left** join ?

Comment: Можно с left можно без.

Comment: ok. Любой стиль оформления кода дело вкуса само собой. Но у вас он как-то не выдержан совсем. В частности: первый подзапрос не имеет отступов, а второй имеет. Перед первым подзапросом скобка не переносится на новую строку, а перед вторым переносится. Комментарии на моём экране не влезли в рамки сниппета. Я бы мог внести улучшающую правку, но боюсь навязывать какой-то определенный стиль.

Comment: хотя нет. не ok. Всё таки запрос должен отражать, то что хотим получить. То что с `left join` приведённый выше запрос работает также как и с `inner join` не повод его использовать, ИМХО. При чтении приходится задумываться почему мы ожидаем получить всё из первого подзапроса, и почему во втором может чего-то не оказаться.

Comment: Я пробовал на рабочей базе, к моему удивлению работало как с null в поле addressCode, но фишка в том, что **rn** никогда не будет null (всегда будет целое число с номером строки), поэтому и inner и left вернут одинаковый результат. А тип join-а я и правда привык всегда указывать. Я думаю что left должно работать быстрее, так как не делается проверка есть ли значение в обеих таблицах (нет проверки на доп-фильтрацию выборки)